# Next.js Link got 404 status code on /api route

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, next.js, vercel

Hoping to get some help from someone who is familiar with Next.js.

I have a link that should lead to the `/api/auth/login`, but it tries to go to `http://127.0.0.1:3000/_next/static/development/pages/api/auth/login.js` which do not exist (and of course, it throw `404`).

The exists one should be `http://127.0.0.1:3000/_next/server/static/development/pages/api/auth/login.js` (have `server` prior `static`).

After it got `404`, it will try again on `http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/auth/login`, so it is still works in the end.

Link to the other routes outside `/api` works as expected.

I have found the similar question on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56418958/why-do-i-get-a-404-for-half-a-second-when-clicking-a-next-js-link-that-just-ca), but it is not answered yet.

---

**NOTE:** I use command `vercel dev` to build.

**NOTE2:** I also use `react-native`, `react-native-web`, `expo` together with the `Next.js`